# Google sheets API update call missing parameter

Tags: php, google-sheets-api

I am trying to update a google spreadsheet using PHP. Currently the code reliably connects and prints values, but when I try to update values, I get:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Exception' with message '(update) missing required param: 'spreadsheetId''

```
$service = new Google_Service_Sheets($client);
$spreadsheetId = '[MyID]';
$range = 'Sheet1!A2:E';

$response = $service->spreadsheets_values->get($spreadsheetId, $range);
$values = $response->getValues();


if (count($values) == 0) {
    print "No data found.\n";
} else {
    foreach ($values as $row) {
        // Print columns A and E, which correspond to indices 0 and 4.
        printf("%s, %s<br>", $row[0], $row[4]);
    }
}

$range = 'Sheet1!A2:E2';
$values = [1,2,3,4,5];
$body = new Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange(['values'=>$values]);
$service->spreadsheets_values->update($spreadsheetId,'Sheet1!A2:E',$body,'raw');
```

The get() call works perfectly, using the same spreadsheet ID. The update call says that it is missing the spreadsheet ID parameter, but prints the correct spreadsheet ID in the call stack.

Is there an issue with the way I am passing the ID in the update call?

---

Issue was not actually with spreadsheet ID, but with the way $values and the value input option was passed in. $values should be a two dimensional array, and value input option should be an array not a string. posted the corrected parts of code below for posterity.

```
$range = 'Sheet1!A2:E2';
$values = [[1,2,3,4,5]];
$inputoption = ['valueInputOption' => "RAW"];
$body = new Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange(['values'=>$values]);
$service->spreadsheets_values->update($spreadsheetId,$range,$body,$inputoption);
```

Comment: Not too familiar with this topic. This does seem strange though for the update: `Sheet1!A2:E'` is that a cell or series of columns?

Comment: That is a range containing every cell from A2 in the top left to the bottom of column E in the bottom right.

Comment: Gotcha. Looking at some docs I see they pass the 4th argument, the `valueInputOption`, as an array. Is the error message maybe misleading? Be nice to see the "raw" request.

Comment: @ficuscr So it turns out the error message WAS misleading, and the actual issue was with the valueInputOption, and the $values. I've posted the final working code and the description of what fixed it. If I could appoint a comment as an answer, it would be yours, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not passing any Oauth2 login credentials, which if I'm not mistaken, is required to add or update information through a Google API (though reading the information does not require this).

https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/php

OR, you are not passing the correct information in $value when trying to update (it may be looking for a specific spreadsheet ID, not a range.

Comment: I've omitted the Oauth2 login information as it was easier than editing out any personally identifiable information. That information is handled through $client, a Google_client with authconfig, scopes and accesstoken in place.

As for the information in value,  update requires a spreadsheet ID,a range, the values passed in, and an input option. It is receiving all of those and in the correct order, as far as I can tell, but complaining that it does not have the spreadsheet ID.

Comment: have a look at this https://www.fillup.io/post/read-and-write-google-sheets-from-php/  what's the 'raw' in your update line for?